# Means plot for 3 way Anova

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova

I am trying to create interaction plots in R. I have the means and would like to draw two separate graphs for variable c when c = 1 and c = 2.  When c = 1, I would like to have A on X axis and B as separate lines and another graph for c = 2.  A similar graph is shown below, with c = 1 condition from my project.  Any suggestions, how to create elegant graphs in R. I have to change the legend with labels, not 1 and 2. similarly X axis should also contain labels.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
fict_mean = fict_data %>% group_by(A, B, C) %>% summarise(mean = mean(dv))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'A', 'B' (override with `.groups` argument)
fict_mean %>% filter(C == 1) %>% ggplot(aes(A, mean)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your data? Copy and paste the output from `dput(fict_data)` in your post

Answer (score 1):

May be we can do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
fict_data %>%
   group_by(A, B, C = factor(C)) %>%
   summarise(dv = mean(dv), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   mutate(A = factor(A), B = str_c('B', B)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = B, values_from = dv) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(group = C)) + 
       geom_line(aes(x = A, y = B1)) + 
       geom_line(aes(x = A, y = B2)) + 
       facet_wrap(~ C) + 
       theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
fict_data <- data.frame(A = sample(1:2, 50, replace = TRUE), 
B = sample(1:2, 50 , replace = TRUE), C = sample(1:2, 50, replace = TRUE),
dv = rnorm(50))
```

Comment: This is showing all four lines in a single graph. I need two separate graphs for the variable C.  i.e., for C = 1, one graph with two lines, C = 2, another graph with two lines.